# Cannot get update query to run from an imploded array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I'm trying to update a table using only changed values, so to do this I need to remove any values in the array that are blank. I've done this using

```
$edit_data = array_filter($edit_data, "check_if_empty");
```

where check_if_empty returns true if the value isn't empty. This works fine, and I'm then doing this to put the data in a format ready for an SQL query:

```
$fields = "`" . implode("`, `", array_keys($edit_data)) . "`";
$fields_data   = implode("'", $edit_data);
```

var_dumping both of these returns what I'd expect (rank being the field name, O-8 being the new value):

> string(6) "`rank`"

and

> string(3) "O-8"

However, I'm then doing this to try and create the UPDATE query:

```
$query = "UPDATE `personnel` SET ({$fields}) VALUES ({$fields_data}) WHERE `user_id` = '$user_id'";
```

echoing this out gives me the following:

> UPDATE `personnel` SET (-8) WHERE `user_id` = '1'

In this case the user_id is 1, so this is fine. However, I'm not sure why the fields and fields_data parts are completely broken. Obviously this query doesn't run, so if anyone has any suggestions that'd be great.

Thanks.

**EDIT:** var_dump($fields):

> string(6) "`rank`"

var_dump($fields_data):

> string(3) "O-8"

**EDIT2:**

So I changed the fields_data line to this:

`$fields_data   = "'" . implode("'", $edit_data) . "'";`

and the ' ' is now appearing around the value as expecting. However, the query still doesn't work. I changed the query to this:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `personnel` ({$fields}) VALUES ({$fields_data})";
```

and it worked fine, so I think the issue is with it not being correct to use UPDATE in this way. If anyone has any ideas as to how I could create an INSERT statement by iterating through the arrays that'd be great.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post var_dumps for $fields and $fields_data exactly before the $query is set.

Comment: Done. I'm not even sure if you can use UPDATE in this way - I know it works for INSERT, but looking up documentation it seems you can only use UPDATE by iterating through each field = field_data in order.

Comment: **WARNING**: This looks [terrifyingly insecure](http://bobby-tables.com/) and for your sake I hope this is not on the public internet. You need to ensure any and all user parameters are [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) or you are at serious risk of an application compromise. Whenever possible use prepared statements and placeholders to ensure you're not exposed to errors of that sort.

Comment: Thanks for the warning: I've considered this, and the data being updated is actually being grabbed from another table in the database (which is being escaped when inserted). This is just to allow for a moderator to approve the request. I figured escaping the same data twice would be a waste of time, but I'm happy to be proven wrong if that's not the case.

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple by using a couple of custom functions to implode and wrap your column names and their associated values.  It's much less error prone than concatenating them manually.

```
/**
 *  Implode and wrap array keys
 */
function implodeKeysWrapped($before, $after, $glue, $array) {
    $out = '';
    foreach ( $array as $k => $v ) {
        $out .= $before.$k.$after.$glue;
    }
    return substr($out, 0, -strlen($glue));
}

/**
 *  Implode and wrap array values
 */
function implodeWrapped($before, $after, $glue, $array) {
    $out = '';
    foreach ( $array as $item ){
        $out .= $before.$item.$after.$glue;
    }

    return substr($out, 0, -strlen($glue));
}

// For example...
$edit_data = array(
    'column1'   => 1,
    'column2'   => 'somestring',
    'column3'   => 'blah'
);

$fields = implodeKeysWrapped('`', '`', ',', $edit_data);
$fields_data = implodeWrapped("'", "'", ',', $edit_data);
$query = "INSERT INTO `personnel` (".$fields.") VALUES (".$fields_data.")";
echo $query;
```